# How to generate single minify file of css using Compass?

Tags: sass, compass

I want to compile my sass file into single minify css in project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Minifying with Sass

In the command line, enter the following:

```
$ sass --watch style.scss:style.css --style compressed
```

### **Minifying with Compass**

First, make sure you’ve setup your project in Compass by entering the following in the command line:

```
$ compass create path/to/your_project
```

Afterwards, you’ll notice that Compass has created two folders in your project directory; /sass/ and /stylesheets/. It has also created a config.rb file.

Open the config.rb file and you should see something that looks a little like the following:

```
# Require any additional compass plugins here.

# Set this to the root of your project when deployed:
http_path = "/"
css_dir = "stylesheets"
sass_dir = "sass"
images_dir = "images"
javascripts_dir = "javascripts"

# You can select your preferred output style here (can be overridden via the command line):
output_style = :compressed # :expanded or :nested or :compact or :compressed

# To enable relative paths to assets via compass helper functions. Uncomment:
# relative_assets = true

# To disable debugging comments that display the original location of your selectors. Uncomment:
line_comments = false


# If you prefer the indented syntax, you might want to regenerate this
# project again passing --syntax sass, or you can uncomment this:
# preferred_syntax = :sass
# and then run:
# sass-convert -R --from scss --to sass sass scss && rm -rf sass && mv scss sass
```

In your config.rb file, Line 11 will likely be commented out with the # sign. Uncomment the output_style line so that it reads like the example above.

Finally, you’ll want to get Compass to start watching for changes to your scss files. In the command line, enter:

```
$ cd /path/to/your_project
$ compass watch
```

And finish!

---

[Credits](https://jonbellah.com/how-to-minify-css-with-sass-and-compass/)

Comment: It would be really cool if you can upvote the answer also! Thanks! :)